# JavaScript get the first letter of the elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom, element

I want to make a program that get the first letter of all of the elements that have the same class.

```js
var email = document.querySelector(".email");
var letter = document.querySelector(".letter");

const nameletter = email.textContent;
letter.innerHTML = nameletter.charAt(0);
```

```css
.letter {
border: 1px solid red;
display: inline-block;
padding: 5px;
background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="letter"></h1>
<span class="email">email@email.com</span>
<br>
<h1 class="letter"></h1>
<span class="email">anotheremail@email.com</span>
```

As you can see, I can only get the first letter from the first element that has the 'email' class. Is there any way to get the second element's first letter?

Comment: Have you tried iterating over them? That would be the place to start

Comment: `document.querySelector` only returns first element in the DOM

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Try `document. querySelectorAll`

Comment: Note that you have an **unsafe assignment** to `innerHTML`. The two easiest workarounds are using [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) or [`.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText).

Comment: @Rojo can you please explain me why is the `innerHTML` is and unsafe assignment?

Comment: [XSS attackers can intercept it and modify it](https://gomakethings.com/preventing-cross-site-scripting-attacks-when-using-innerhtml-in-vanilla-javascript/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `querySelectorAll` instead and iterating over them:

```js
var email = document.querySelectorAll(".email");
var letter = document.querySelectorAll(".letter");

for(var i = 0; i < email.length; i++) {
  const nameletter = email[i].textContent;
  letter[i].innerHTML = nameletter.charAt(0);
}
```

```css
.letter {
border: 1px solid red;
display: inline-block;
padding: 5px;
background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="letter"></h1>
<span class="email">email@email.com</span>
<br>
<h1 class="letter"></h1>
<span class="email">anotheremail@email.com</span>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is how I tried before but I created a new var and I used it in the for loop this is why it did not work.